# Inability to retrieve unicode resultset

Tags: mysql, unicode, jdbc

I have been able to successfully insert unicode values into my database but am not able to retrieve them through a java resultset. The same query fetches data from the mysql query browser. The sql reads thus:

```
SELECT book_name FROM book_resource_user_view WHERE MATCH(book_name) AGAINST ('तेरा मुझसे है पेहला का नाता कोई') limit 25
```

Before attempting the select statement, I did this:

```
String query = "set names utf8";
        state.executeUpdate(query);
```

Still no success? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the tables and the output (e.g. command line window or website) UTF-8 ?

Comment: the tables are utf-8. What do you mean by the output being utf-8?

Comment: what's more, the resultset shows as empty i.e. it does not enter the while (results.next()) loop.

Comment: How are you debugging you queried results? I think you'll display it somewhere – are you sure that the data is correctly returned as UTF-8 but probably garbled afterwards within the output?

Comment: show String query = "show variables";

Comment: I cannot see that because the resultset shows as empty. However, like I said, the same query returns results when queried through mysql query browser

Comment: in "show variables", what should I look for?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that a straight retrieve does happen. However, when the retrieve is based on a match like in the case above,  data isn't retrieved. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have found the answer. I had modified the keyword variable using

```
keyword = new String(keyword.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

After I commented that statement and used the keyword variable directly from the form, it seems to work.

Comment: Still not consistent though. Some strings throw up a result while others don't